# Build and Deployment of nodejs with angular using asude pipeline and appservice

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In my local system I have built the Angular application with `npm build` and in node js (I have removed the dist of nodejs and pasted the Angular dist) and I published it. Now I want this setup in Azure so, I just built the Angular code using Azure Pipeline and created the artifact I.e) contains dist in the artifact, (I have the confusion as whether we need to provide this dist to the nodejs) if yes, how to do this by single Azure Pipeline both Angular and node js and how to deploy both the Angular and nodejs in the same webapp (app service).

If any other methods for this build and deployment please suggest it.

Need the guidance on angular building and replacing the dist of node js with Angular in 1 Azure Pipeline and deploying of both Angular and node js in 1 appservice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In order to deploy angular app you need to first build the Angular app in your Azure devops pipeline and save the build artifact in the dist folder, Then use the dist build folder for deployment via Release pipeline to Azure Web app, Refer below:-

**My build pipeline:-**

Below code [**reference**](https://www.azure365pro.com/how-to-deploy-angular-app-to-azure-using-devops-pipelines/#)

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'dist'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Before deploying the Web app via Release pipeline, Make sure to add below settings in your ***Azure Web app > Configuration > General Settings > Startup command:-***

```bash
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/my-appangular --no-daemon --spa
```

[image]

**Use this Build artifact in Release pipeline like below:-**

[image]

**Now, Select Deploy Azure App Service task like below:-**

*Select build artifact path in Package or folder:-*

[image]

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Azure web app > Advanced tools > Go > Site wwroot***

[image]

**Angular app is running successfully:-**

[image]

***To deploy the angular web app in a single yaml pipeline refer the yaml script below:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'dist'
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'subscription-id xxxxx'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'valleywebapp09'
    packageForLinux: 'dist'
    StartupCommand: pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/my-appangular --no-daemon --spa
```

Make sure to change the startup command in Azure Web app > Configuration > startup command to below:-

[image]

```bash
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/my-appangular --no-daemon --spa
```

Advanced tool kudu:-

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: thank you, but i just want the nodejs build and deployment as well

Comment: @karthik If you want to build and deploy in a same build yaml deployment use the yaml code below this line in my answer - To deploy the angular web app in a single yaml pipeline refer the yaml script below:-