# Getting error in Azure Web App Deploy - Package not found

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines

When I try to pipeline job to add it to a web app in azure portal I get this following error:

> No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip
> Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as
> an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

[image: pipeline error]

What to do?

I have tried none as I am stuck at beginner stage.

Comment: Is this YAML or UI Designer-based? Build or Release pipeline? Can you post information about your pipeline, please

Comment: Based on the steps of your pipeline agent job from the screenshot, you tried to deploy the `*.zip` file onto Azure Web App service with `AzureWebApp@1` task **as soon as** having checked out the code from your repo onto the Windows MS-hosted agent. Without adding any another task to generate this zip file. This task is sure to fail unless the `*.zip` file is already there in your repo. If not, plesae check the answer by @SiddheshDesai to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi @SanjayVishnaw, have you got a chance to check the answer and suggestions on this topic? May I know if the troubleshooting information helps resolve your issue? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

> No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

No package error occurs, Because the Deploy step was unable to find the Azure Web app build package in D:\a\1\s***.zip path. Refer my [**SO thread answer1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440816/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-1-websitebr/76472534#76472534) to resolve this error. Cross check in which folder your Build is generated, In my answer when I was adding - `'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'` and `'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'` in package while deploying web app, I received same No package found error. Then I checked in which folder my package was doenloaded, It was downloaded in - /home/vsts/work/1/publishedApp which is `Agent.BuildDirectory` according to Predefined variables of Azure DevOps. Refer here- [Predefined variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) You also verify the package path and check the predefined variable and add it in your pipeline.

***Approach 1:-***

If you are deploying Angular app, ***Make sure to build your app and once the dist folder is created, Deploy your dist folder in Azure Web app via Azure DevOps YAML pipeline. Reference MY [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76985518/build-and-deployment-of-nodejs-with-angular-using-asude-pipeline-and-appservice/76990599#76990599)***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
    

  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'dist'
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: ' subscription (xxxxxx7cb2a7)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'valleywebapp98'
    packageForLinux: 'dist'
    StartupCommand: pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/my-appangular --no-daemon --spa
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Approach 2:-***

**One more alternative is to use the pipeline below:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'dist' # Assuming 'dist' is your build output folder
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist.zip' # Define the path for the zip file
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*.zip' # Assuming you want to copy all zip files
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: ' subscription (xxxxxx97cb2a7)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'valleywebapp98'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop/dist.zip' # Specify the path to the zip file
    StartupCommand: 'pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/my-appangular --no-daemon --spa'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]